# Print Label only on First Candle using Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to create a position sizing calculator in which i want to have a label only on the first 5 min candle in which i will have a position size and the difference between high low of the first candle. The problem is my code is printing label on every 5 min candle but i only want the label on the first candle. here is the code. Please help

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script",overlay = true)
positionSize = (500/(high-low))
high_low = high-low 


    positionLlbl = label.new(0, na,text="PS: "+ str.tostring(positionSize, "#"), color=color.rgb(255, 255, 255), yloc=yloc.abovebar)
    label.set_size(positionLlbl, size.normal)
    label.set_style(positionLlbl,label.style_label_down)

    highlowLbl = label.new(0, na,text="HL: " + str.tostring(high_low, "#"), color=color.rgb(255, 255, 255), yloc=yloc.belowbar)
    label.set_size(positionLlbl, size.normal)
    label.set_style(highlowLbl,label.style_label_up)

    // label.delete(positionLlbl[1]) 
    // label.delete(highlowLbl[1])
```

Comment: What do you call 'the first candle' ? The frst candle on your screen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the built-in function `session.isfirstbar_regular` allows you to determine the first candle of a new session in the context of the current chart timeframe.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script",overlay = true)
positionSize = (500/(high-low))
high_low = high-low 

if session.isfirstbar_regular
    positionLlbl = label.new(bar_index, high,text="PS: "+ str.tostring(positionSize, "#"), color=color.rgb(255, 255, 255), yloc=yloc.abovebar, style = label.style_label_down)
    highlowLbl = label.new(bar_index, low,text="HL: " + str.tostring(high_low, "#"), color=color.rgb(255, 255, 255), yloc=yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_label_up)
```

[image]
[session.isfirstbar_regular](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_session%7Bdot%7Disfirstbar_regular)

> Returns true on the first regular session bar of the day, `false`
> otherwise. The result is the same whether extended session information
> is used or not.